# My code not working with select

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

I know this has been asked but I can't find a solution after looking all over this site and tutorials on others. I have DELETE, SELECT(*) and INSERT statements working with almost the same syntax but for some reason this won't work. I'm trying to return a list of files a user has created from a database, here is my Javascript and PHP:

```
Javascript:
$('#btnLoad').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataString ='emailHolder=' + email;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process_load.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        });

    });
```

and the process_load.php file:

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'psl-config.php';



        $email = $_POST['emailHolder'];
        $query="SELECT filename from maps WHERE email=?";
        $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);


    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
$stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    /* execute statement */
        $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
        $stmt->bind_result($email);

    /* fetch values */
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            printf ("%s\n", $email);
        }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

    ?>
```

I appreciate any help you can give me.

EDIT: Sorry, I was binding the parameter but accidentally removed it when trying to throw the kitchen sink at the problem. Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: you have given the datatype json, so you have to json_encode your output

Comment: You have a ? in your query but I cant see where you bind a value to it

Comment: Where is the value that you should be binding to email?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add it back in when I was cleaning up the code. When I was trying different things I must have accidentally removed it, which obviously created more problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `bind_param()`. Secondly, the Javascript is expecting JSON but you're just outputing the raw emails separated by new lines. Change to:

```
$output = array(); // build an array that can be json encoded

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email); // bind the param in the WHERE clause

    /* execute statement */
        $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
        $stmt->bind_result($email);

    /* fetch values */
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $output[] = $email; // append to the array
        }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

echo json_encode($output); // output json
```

Now you can get the email array on the Javascript side:

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process_load.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data){
                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    console.log( data[i] ); // logs each email
                }
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you are trying to sit at two chairs at once. Or even more chairs.

Having no working server side code, and even having no idea how to write it, you are already trying to write JS and AJAX. As a result, you have a pile of quite random lines of code banged together and have no idea why it doesn't work.

## It doesn't work this way.

- **First**, you have to learn how to work with mysqli. In general.
- **Only after that** you can try to write server-side code.
- **And finally**, only after making your server side part work with mocked data, you may start with JS.